# Why is this test failing - Not Implemented Error Rspec 3.1.x and Rails 4.1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am testing the following method:

```
  def deal_with_response(site, responses, request_url)
    response.each do |response|
      if response.code == 200
        send_request(site.site_api_url, site.site_api_key, response, request_url)
      elsif response.code == 404
        send_request(site.site_api_url, site.site_api_key, response, request_url)
        GeneralMailer.recieved_404(ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_NAME'], ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_EMAIL'], site, response).deliver_now
      elsif response.code == 500
        send_request(site.site_api_url, site.site_api_key, response, request_url)
        GeneralMailer.recieved_500(ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_NAME'], ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_EMAIL'], site, response).deliver_now
      else
        send_request(site.site_api_url, site.site_api_key, response, request_url)
        GeneralMailer.recieved_error(ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_NAME'], ENV['ADMINISTRATOR_EMAIL'], site, response).deliver_now
      end
    end
  end
```

Which is tested by this code:

```
it "should send no email (200)" do
  response = double("response", :code => 200)
  site = double("site", :site_api_url => 'http://google.ca', site_api_key: 'sdsadsasada')
  send_request_method = double()
  send_request_method.stub(:send_request).with(site.site_api_url, site.site_api_key, [response], 'http://google.ca').and_return nil

  expect{ BlackBird::PublishToSites::User.deal_with_response(response) }.to_not change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
end
```

The result is:

```
 Failure/Error: expect{ BlackBird::PublishToSites::User.deal_with_response(response) }.to_not change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
 NotImplementedError:
   `expect { }.not_to change { }.by()` is not supported
 # ./spec/blackbird/publish_to_sites/user_spec.rb:129:in `(root)'
```

Am I missing something? I was doing similar code like this in other tests and it works fine. Did I dod the expect block wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message goes, `expect {}.not_to change { }.by()` is not supported. When you use change matcher with `not_to`, you can only specify the `from` value.

Try either of the followings:

```
expect{ BlackBird::PublishToSites::User.deal_with_response(response) }.to_not change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }

expect{ BlackBird::PublishToSites::User.deal_with_response(response) }.to_not change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.from(original_delivery_count)
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers#change-instance_method